# Close: off-topic, missing returns

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have this question:

When i use:

```
async function createElement(req,res){
   const time1 = new Date().getTime();
   console.log("turn on time 1 ",time1)
   await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve,1000));
   await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve,1000));
   const time2 = new Date().getTime();
   console.log("turn on time 2 ",time2)
   console.log('result : ', time2 - time1);
}
```

the result is:

```
turn on time 1 1531957505408
turn on time 2 1531957507413
result : 2005
```

and is fine, but when i try use promise.all with await

```
async function createElement(req,res){
let fn1 = () => {
    new Promise((resolve) => {

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("message from fn1")
            resolve()
       },1000)
    });
}
let fn2 = () => {
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
             console.log("message from fn2")
             resolve()
        },1000)

    });
}
const time1 = new Date().getTime();
console.log("turn on time 1 ",time1)
let responses = await Promise.all([fn1(),fn2()])
console.log("waiting for responses")
const time2 = new Date().getTime();
console.log("turn on time 2 ",time2)
console.log('result : ', time2 - time1);
}
```

the result is:

```
turn on time 1 1531957505408
turn on time 2  1531957505408
result 0
message from fn1
message from fn2
```

so... in the case that i need the result to fn1 or/and fn2 for other operation, how i can to wait the response to promise.all

Comment: `fn1` and `fn2` don't return a created promise. Make them return a promise and it should work.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. Typo: missing `return`s.

Comment: you can also just remove the outer `{}` in those arrow functions for an implicit return :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning promise from fn1 and fn2.

```js
async function createElement(req,res){
let fn1 = () => {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("message from fn1")
            resolve()
       },1000)
    });
}
let fn2 = () => {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
             console.log("message from fn2")
             resolve()
        },1000)

    });
}
const time1 = new Date().getTime();
console.log("turn on time 1 ",time1)
let responses = await Promise.all([fn1(),fn2()])
console.log("waiting for responses")
const time2 = new Date().getTime();
console.log("turn on time 2 ",time2)
console.log('result : ', time2 - time1);
}

createElement();
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` the promises from your functions